# Resonant Radar -- How aspect independent is it?

Tags: signal, radio, signal-processing, resonance, radar

Resonant Radar: transmitting at a bandwidth that encapsulates nearly the natural resonance frequency of a reflective object in hopes of illuminating it upon return (higher amplitude.)

I have read that resonant radar is **aspect independent,** the **resonances do not change** based on how the object is oriented / positioned in front of the antennas.

So say I wanted to place a few strips of highly reflective metals as pictured below, if I were to transmit with a radar sweep at a bandwidth that illuminates each of these metals, I have a question:

- Would you predict the late time response to be **different** when I rearrange the order of the metal strips?  (All other variables kept constant.)

Again it is aspect independent but at ~1m away, and with no background reflection, will the **multipath** of these reflected returns vary enough for it to be evident that the order of metals changed? (After a lot of signal processing (eg. generalized pencil of function.)

Just from your expertise, what do you predict to occur? This would be a good experiment but I'd like to have an idea of the product before investing in the expensive equipment (plan to develop a pulsed radar system with software-defined radio.)

[image]

Comment: I think: since all plates are electrically conductive, all the plates look **identical** from the radar's perspective. The radar will be unable to distinguish one from the other.

Comment: What frequency is your radar going to be operating at?

Comment: 500 Mhz - 1500 Mhz

Comment: I don't know.  But even though all those materials are electrically conductive, they have different properties such as permeability that may affect how they "interact" with the incident electromagnetic (EM) wave.  All of the radiator models I've seen use aluminum for the material.  I have not seen a comparison of the same design made with, for instance, copper.

Comment: Another thing.  At 500 MHz the wavelength is ~0.6 meters.  That means that the scenario you described, horns ~1 meter away from the reflectors, means that this is a near-field problem, where the distances are less than 10 wavelengths.

Comment: This smacks of nonsense pseudo-science -1

Comment: "I have read that…" **always** tell us *where* you've read this. I can imagine there  is something to the principles of this, but this really is off by basically all parameters that you're describing and hence makes no sense, physically.

Answer (score 2):

> Just from your expertise, what do you predict to occur?

- Your block of metal to radio waves just is a block of metal. The difference in properties is absolutely negligible at these very low radar frequencies.
- Your block of metal is in the near field of your horn antennas; you're not building a radar system, you're building a bad capacitor with extra steps.

So, no, this wouldn't yield any interesting results, at all.